# Mistake with a loop

Tags: bash, shell, azure

I have a little problem with my loop.

I have a array:blob_name= (vendors orders)

a variable: file_to_upload = **/json_file/*
There is 2 files in the folder json_file : vendors.json and orders.json

```
for f in $file_to_upload
  do
  for l in ${blob_name[*]}
   do
   echo $l
   echo $f
 az storage blob upload --container-name $container_name --file $f --name $l
   done
  done
```

Actual result:

- Vendors
- **/json_file/orders.json
- Orders
- **/json_file/orders.json
- Vendors
- **/json_file/vendors.json
- Orders
- **/json_file/vendors.json

Expected result:

- Vendors
- **/json_file/vendors.json
- Orders
- **/json_file/orders.json

Comment: Unless you enabled the `globstar` option, `**/json_file/*` treats `**` as two separate `*` wild cards, neither of which match the current directly `.`. The resulting non-matching pattern is treated (by default) as a single literal string.

Comment: the ** is just for hide, normaly I'm using a path

Comment: Then you need to post *actual* code that reproduces your problem.Whatever `file_to_upload` is, it's not undergoing the pathname expansion you expect, and instead is treated as a single literal string.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, my loop with file_upload is correct. Now in --name I have to define one name for the first file and another name for the second.
So I create a antoher loop with blob_name but have problem with him

Comment: I think I got your actual and expected results confused. The point is, your outer loop is executing twice, not once, and the value of `file_to_upload` is the only thing that could cause that.

Comment: Oh ok, i have 2 files in my file_to_upload and got 2 element in my array ..

Comment: I think what you want is a single loop, `for l in "${blob_name[@]}"; do f=/path/to/json_file/$l.json; ...`.

Comment: Ok thank you very much